# What happens when the version column hits int max in the Orleans Storage table?

Tags: c#, sql, orleans

I'm using Microsoft Orleans (C#) with ADO on SQL Server for persistence. I see in the OrleansStorage table on the Version column it is using the INT datatype. Does anyone know how an INT rollover is handled?

Every time I save the state of the grain, the version increments.

Comment: I don't know what Orleans is or "saving the state of the grain" is but if that's the only thing that increments the number you would need to do it once a second for 68 years before overflowing an `int`

Answer (score 0):

When you try to insert a value that exceeds the bounds of a data type in the SQL Server, you get an error that tells you this and you can't insert and new version until you change the datatype for something bigger.

but integers are 32 or 64 bit depending on operating system, so that the sql server will run out of numbers earlier that the application

Comment: I was more interested in the behavior of the Orleans framework when that happens. Does it rollover the value by itself? Or does it require that the record be manually removed?

Comment: the oms will produce a sql INSERT command, which will fail, because the server can not insert, that goes for each oms that works with SQL Server